# Как выйти из полноэкранного режима Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я делаю программу где можно писать код, и я столкнулся с проблемой.
Изначально нельзя изменять размер окна (resizable), но когда я открываю проект то можно, и если я его закрою (По идее все должно было стать на свои места и снова нельзя было бы изменять размер окна) но если я сначало поставлю окно с открытым проектом в полноэкранный режим и закрою его, то границы не возвратятся назад. Вот скриншоты

[image: Главное меню программы]

[image: Открытый проект в полноэкранном режиме]

[image: Моя проблема]

На последнем скриншоте я закрыл проект, и не выключил полноэкранный режим.
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("585x400")
win.resizable(False, False)

#...

def Open():
    #...
    win.resizable(True, True)

def Close():
    #...
    win.geometry("585x400")
    win.resizable(False, False)

#...

win.mainloop()
```

Можно ли как-то через код выйти из полноэкранного режима?
Если кто не понял, про полноэкранный режим я имел ввиду данную кнопку на панели окна

[image: Кнопка развернуть в полноэкранный режим]

Comment: Зачем вы используете код для python2?

Comment: @СергейКох, я еще учу его и не знаю где код python 2 версии и где 3

Comment: @DMITRY1234455 там где видите импорт `from Tkinter import *` с Tkinter с большой буквы - это код для Python 2. Сам код по факту может отличаться только этим импортом, но если у вас такой импорт работает, значит вы установили и используете Python 2. Сейчас нет особого смысла начинать изучать Python с версии 2, лучше его удалить и использовать Python 3.

Comment: @insolor а, ой, извините, я писал код который в вопросе и нечаянно с большой буквы написал, сам код у меня на python 3, щас отредактирую на маленькую букву